# Get related id in trigger

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, before-trigger, before-save-flow

I have an object `course_reg__c` with master-detail to objects `course__c` and `Opportunity`. From `Opportunity`, there is a lookup to `Account`.

I have created a record triggered after insert flow on `course_reg__c` which updates the related `Opportunity.AccountId` to a field in `course_reg__c`. The field name is `oppAcctId__c`.

I also have a form assembly form in which I am creating a `course_reg__c` record, and I have to get the related `AccountId` in the record created from formassembly in salesforce. For this purpose I have created the flow.

I have a before-insert trigger on ecr for some other updates in account object. Here I have to access this `oppAcctId` field in the trigger somehow.

But since the trigger runs while the creation first I won't get the account id at the time of execution. After this, the flow runs, and the value is updated.

So is there any way I can use this field with the value in the trigger first?
I need this value to perform another update in the trigger, but this value is obtained from another flow.

Now the trigger runs and I wont get the value and then the flow runs in initial scenario according to the order of execution.

Comment: I recommend you try to avoid using shortened words/acronyms.

Comment: You're probably going to need to take another stab at explaining this. I read it a couple of times. The big picture still isn't sinking in.

Comment: @pchittum I have elaborated my issue. Please check.

Comment: "before-insert trigger on ecr" -- what is ecr?  Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: Agreed about ECR, too. @Ash I made an edit above to help you see what most people on this forum would expect when talking about object names. Generally, using the developer/API name of objects and fields will help everyone understand/infer where you're talking about a standard object or custom object. It makes it way easier to grok what someone is describing, IMO. Glad you got your answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change your first Flow to run before the record is saved then the field will be updated before the trigger runs.

Otherwise, I would recommend moving all your logic to triggers. This will make it easier to manage as all the logic will be in one place.

(To check the order of execution after a record is created/updated, you can use the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).)